# Close and reopen fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have a fancybox with dynamically loaded images. When clicked on an image in the gallery a fancybox popped open. It needs to be possible to navigate trough the images with next and previous keys.

The href in a#singleimage is the image that gets dynamically changed.
My fancybox closes, but a new fancybox doesn't pop up.

This is my code:

```
if($.fancybox.isOpen){
fireFancybox();
}

function fireFancybox(){
$.fancybox.close();

$('a#single_image').fancybox({
    'padding': 0,
    'margin': 45,
    'showCloseButton':true,
    'keys':{
        close  : [27], 
        toggle : [70]  
    }
});
}
```

Anyone got any toughts?

Note: The code for triggering events on certain keydowns is correct, so no problems there.